# Why need to convert from Integer to int

Tags: java

I encountered a problem when I use TreeMap.

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> a = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    a.put(5,1);
    a.put(3,2);
    a.put(4,3);
    int target = 7;
    System.out.println(target - a.get(5)); //line 6
    for(Map.Entry b : a.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(target - b.getValue()); //line 8
    }
```

The code above gave me an compile error. However, when I change the line 8 to this:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> a = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    a.put(5,1);
    a.put(3,2);
    a.put(4,3);
    int target = 7;
    System.out.println(target - a.get(5)); //line 6
    for(Map.Entry b : a.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(target - (int) b.getValue()); //line 8
    }
```

Then it works. Could anyone give me some ideas why I don't need any change in line 6 but need convert an Integer to int in line 8?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You ignored the "raw type" warning in the `for` statement.  It should be:

```
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> b : a.entrySet()) {
        ...
```

The raw type would cause `getValue()` to return `Object`.  If you provide the type parameters then the compiler knows it will return `Integer`, and this will get unboxed automatically.

Comment: Oh!!! Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you need to define the type there or would the diamond operator (Map.Entry<>) be enough (which was introduced with Java 7) as a.entrySet() already defines the type? Using nothing at all like in the OP of course causes the error.

Comment: @Thomas - You need to define the type.  Just using the diamond operator will give you a compile-time error.

Comment: @Thomas one could of course use `map.foreach((k, v) -> dostuff)`, which would not require types.

Answer (score 5):

There are more than one operations that are underneath `(int) b.getValue()`. First `getValue()` returns `Object` and then that is casted to `Integer` which is then unboxed to `int` . `a.get()` in it's own immediately returns `Integer` since you declared a with Integer in <> (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object) it returns the V type).

The `target - b.getValue()` didn't compile because it was `int - Object` operation which is not defined for operator `-` . That is why you have to do cast to `(int)` .

Following wont work even though b is referring to the object that is `Integer`.

```
Integer a = 1;
Object  b = a;
System.out.println(3 - b); // compile time error "bad operand types for binary operator '-'"
```

Following works

```
Integer a = 1;
Object  b = a;
System.out.println(3 - a);
```

Also works

```
Integer a = 1;
Object  b = a;
System.out.println(3 - (int) b); //this is when you say to compiler not to worry since you are sure that object reference refers to the object that is Integer.
```

Though if at runtime b doesn't refer to int the cast will fail. Even if it did compile in the first place.

```
Integer a = 1;
String  s = "shouldn't work at runtime";
Object  b = s;
System.out.println(3 - (int) b); //this  will compile but fail at runtime
```